# Error with Ionic build in Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I didn’t do anything but since last week, if I try Ionic build, Android shows an error like this:
[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTX3o.png)

I tried some solutions but the error is still showing. Please help if somebody has a solution or idea.

Answer (score 0):

Run `ionic info` 
if you are using `Ionic 3` try 
`ionic cordova platform remove android && npm install  ionic@3.15.0  --save  && ionic cordova platform add android`.